# Cannot serialize member of type System.ComponentModel.ISite

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

I am trying to run vector.asmx in web browser and getting the following error. What is the problem?

Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface.

[my code]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Vector
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Vector : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        public double X { get; set; }

        public double Y { get; set; }

        public double Z { get; set; }





        [WebMethod]
        public double MagnitudeSquared()
        {
            return X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z;
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public double Magnitude()
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(MagnitudeSquared());
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static Vector operator -(Vector v1, Vector v2)
        {
            Vector result = new Vector();

            result.X = v1.X - v2.X;
            result.Y = v1.Y - v2.Y;
            result.Z = v1.Z - v2.Z;

            return result;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static Vector operator +(Vector v1, Vector v2)
        {
            Vector result = new Vector();

            result.X = v1.X + v2.X;
            result.Y = v1.Y + v2.Y;
            result.Z = v1.Z + v2.Z;

            return result;
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public static Vector operator *(Vector v1, double factor)
        {
            Vector result = new Vector();

            result.X = v1.X * factor;
            result.Y = v1.Y * factor;
            result.Z = v1.Z * factor;

            return result;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Vector Clone()
        {
            Vector result = new Vector();

            result.X = this.X;
            result.Y = this.Y;
            result.Z = this.Z;

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return the Vector class. That would be a reference to an instance of the service, which makes no sense.

---

In fact, your entire service makes no sense. A web service is a specialized class. Normal OO concepts like combining data and behavior don't work. You should have one class like `Vector` that contains all of the public data, and another class `VectorService` which is the service itself. It would accept parameters of type `Vector`, and would return such  values as well.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I now doing it the way you suggested. I am getting error in following method in WS can u tell me why

[WebMethod]
        public static Vector operator -(Vector v1, Vector v2)

[error message] One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

Comment: You can't have an operator as a webmethod. Just instance methods.